# How to redirect to action mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC app and I would like it so when an error occurs I call another action which loads a different view.

```
public ActionResult Invoices()
{
    invoiceClass invoice = getInvoice();
    //do stuff with invoice
}

public invoiceClass getInvoice()
{
    invoiceClass invoice = new invoiceClass();
    try
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return invoice;
}
```

I have a method that is very similar to this, when I step through the code, the exception is caught and it hits the redirect call then goes to the return and continues without redirecting. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is an HTTP entry point, you should be returning an `ActionResult`.

```
public ActionResult stuff()
{
    try
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Return a RedirectResult
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //Return a JsonResult
    //Example: return the JSON data { "number": 1 }
    return Json(new { number = 1 });
}
```

## Edit

Here is how I would address your question given the edits you just made.

```
public ActionResult Invoices()
{
    try
    {
        invoiceClass invoice = getInvoice();
        //do stuff with invoice
        return Json(...);
    }
    catch
    {
        //Catch the exception at the top level
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}

public invoiceClass getInvoice()
{
    invoiceClass invoice = new invoiceClass();
    // Do stuff; possibly throw exception if something goes wrong
    return invoice;
}
```

Comment: Although I am not sure whether this is the right place or not but I have a doubt and that is..Do we need to use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` only incase it returned a `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`?

Comment: @aritra Yes you do, if this is an HTTP GET.

Comment: Hi, sorry i was lazy with my example, when i try to implement your answer I get errors because the ActionMethod that calls the methods need to be given the correct type. I cant seem to implement both the redirect if unsucessfull and return the object if successfull

Comment: @BrianPeach I updated the answer to reflect the changes in your question.

Comment: @TimothyShields Thanks for your help, thats done the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a **return**

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

And don't forget to change your return type to `ActionResult`

Answer (score 0):

So Ive managed to find a solution to this problem however I'm certain there will be a better more efficient way.

```
public ActionResult Invoices()
{
    try{
        invoiceClass invoice = getInvoice();
        //do stuff with invoice
    }catch (exception e){
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}

public invoiceClass getInvoice()
{
    invoiceClass invoice = new invoiceClass();
    try
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        index(); //<--the action result
    }
    return invoice;
}
```

calling index() runs through the method then throws an exception in the Invoices() method which then redirects.